# Always show horizontal scroll for div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scrollbar

Here's the basic template I have right now for my code (ReactJS), stripped down to what's required for my question. Here's a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-greider-56g67m?file=/src/App.js).

```
<div style={{maxHeight: "500px", overflowY: "auto"}}>
  <pre>
    <code>
     //bunch of code to display on UI
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

At any position other that at the bottom, the horizontal scroll bar is not there:

[image]

The horizontal scroll bar only shows when I scroll down to the bottom of the div:

[image]

How do I get a successfully working horizontal scroll bar to always show on the div, without having to scroll all the way down (and also remove the scroll bar that currently exists when I scroll down to the bottom)?

**Edit:** Figured it out:

```
.App pre {
  overflow-x: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: I think this is very easy to do. If I recall you can use the sticky attribute on your CSS class to make it stay on the screen. If you post all of your code in a MRE (minimum reproducible example) we can help you further

Comment: change `overflowY:auto` to `overflowY:scroll`

Comment: @MFerguson Here's a Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-greider-56g67m?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: @TheDuo That does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it myself. Adding this fixed the problem. Check [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-greider-56g67m?file=/src/App.js).

```
.App pre {
  overflow-x: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change `overflowY: "auto"` to `overflowY:"scroll"`

Comment: This does not work for me. Please try changing that property here and see that it does not fix the horizontal scroll bar: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-greider-56g67m?file=/src/App.js